# Git new way of maintain two repositories which shares same files

Tags: git

Let's say there are two git repositories living independently:

### repo_A structure

```
repo_A
├── dependencies
│   └── from_repo_B
│       └── script_B
└── other_stuff_A
    ├── script_1
    └── script_2
```

### repo_B structure

```
repo_B
├── common
│   └── script_B
└── other_stuff_B
    ├── script_4
    └── srcipt_3
```

**Repo_A** scripts have to use files inside **common** folder from **repo_B**. They are manually copied to **from_repo_B** folder about once a month or after significant changes made on **repo_B** side (let's call it release process). Scripts in **Repo_B/other_stuff_B** folder are also using **script_B** code.
There is a bottleneck which is review and merge time for **repo_A**. This time for **repo_B** is significantly shorter.

Sometimes there is need to quick fix **script_B** code directly on **repo_A**. In this case there are two pull requests on each repository created.

Changing **script_B** file on **repo_B** can broke **script_1** and **script_2** during the release process. Changes solving these problems are made on **repo_B** then release process is repeated.

Can someone see more clever way of maintain these repositories? I was thinking about Google repo tool but developers who are working only on **repo_A** and are not touching **script_B** file will not be pleased with the new way of preparing repository for development (repo sync etc.). Maybe git subtree? Git submodule? Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asked (and answered) even [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-subtree) a lot of times:

Use [Git subtree](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-subtree)

- Restructure your repos and **move shared trees** of code into separate additional new repos
- Add repos from the above into target repos with subtree's "magic"
- Use repos in the usual way